# Why is my CCParticleExplosion Leaking Memory?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have the following code:

```
CCParticleExplosion *explosion = [[CCParticleExplosion alloc] init];
    explosion.texture = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"chick.png"];
    explosion.position = egg.position;
    [explosion setAutoRemoveOnFinish:YES];
    [explosion setTotalParticles:10];
    [self.layer addChild:explosion];
```

I thought that setAutoRemoveOnFinish will automatically remove the explosion node from the layer and release it. But the xCode instruments says that CCParticleExplosion is leaking memory!

UPDATE 1:

Solved the problem by using CCParticleExplosion node instead of alloc.

Answer (score 1):

If you allocate something into memory, you must deallocate it.

Node is a creation method that handles memory allocation with an autorelease pool.

Answer (score 1):

```
[ explosion autorelease];
```

add above line to your code.

```
CCParticleExplosion *explosion = [[CCParticleExplosion alloc] init];
    explosion.texture = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"chick.png"];
    explosion.position = egg.position;
    [explosion setAutoRemoveOnFinish:YES];
    [explosion setTotalParticles:10];
    [self.layer addChild:explosion];
    [ explosion autorelease];
```

Answer (score 0):

just use `[explosion release];` after you're done using it